# ReactJS: Why is passing the component initial state a prop an anti-pattern?

Tags: reactjs

I've created a small ReactJS dashboard with the help of SocketIO for live updates. Even though I have the dashboard updating, it bugs me that I'm not quite sure if I did it correctly.

What bugs me the most is the [Props in getInitialState as anti-pattern](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html) post. I've created a dashboard that gets live updates from a server, requiring no user interaction beyond loading the page. From what I've read, `this.state` should contain things that will determine whether the component should be re-rendered, and `this.props`.... I don't know yet.

However, when you initially call `React.render(<MyComponent />, ...)`, you can only pass props. In my case, I get all data from the server, so the initial props just end up in `this.state` anyway. So all of my components have something like this:

```
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        progress: this.props.progress,
        latest_update: this.props.latest_update,
        nearest_center: this.props.nearest_center
    }
}
```

Which, unless I've misinterpreted the aforementioned blog post, is an anti-pattern. But I see no other way of injecting the state into the Component, and I don't understand why it's an anti-pattern unless I relabel all of my props to prepend `initial` on them. If anything, I feel like *that's* an anti-pattern because now I have to keep track of more variables than I did before (those prepended with `initial` and those without).

Comment: In 2017, Facebook demonstrates using props to set initial state in their documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor

Comment: @Rohmer's link contains a link to [You probably don't need derived state](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html), which has in-depth discussion of the alternatives, and what to avoid.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

> **Disclaimer**: When I answered this question I was learning / trying to
>   implement vanilla Flux and I was a bit skeptic about it. Later on I
>   migrated everything to Redux. So, an advice: Just go with Redux or
>   MobX. Chances are you won't even need the answer to this question
>   anymore (except for the science).

Passing the intial state to a component as a `prop` is an anti-pattern because the `getInitialState` method is only called the first time the component renders. Meaning that, if you re-render that component passing a **different** value as a `prop`, the component will not react accordingly, because the component will keep the state from the first time it was rendered. It's very error prone.

And here is what you should do:

Try to make your components as stateless as possible. Stateless components are easier to test because they render an **output** based on an **input**. Simple like that.

**But hey.. my components data change.. I can't make them stateless**

Yes you can, for most of them. In order to do that, select an outer component to be the state holder. Using your example, you could create a `Dashboard` component that contains the data, and a `Widget` component that is completely stateless. The `Dashboard` is responsible for getting all the data and then rendering multiple `Widgets` that receive everything they need through `props`.

**But my widgets have some state.. the user can configure them. How do I make them stateless?**

Your `Widget` can expose events that, when handled, cause the state contained in `Dashboard` to change, causing every `Widget` to be rerendered. You create "events" in your `Widget` by having `props` that receive a function.

**Ok, so now, Dashboard keeps the state, but how do I pass the initial state to it?**

You have two options. The most recomended one, is that you make an Ajax call in the `Dashboard` `getInitialState` method to get the initial state from the server. You can also use [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/), which is a more sophisticated way for managing data. Flux is more of a pattern, rather than an implementation. You can use pure Flux with the Facebook's implementation of the `Dispatcher`, but you can use third-party implementations like [Redux](https://github.com/gaearon/redux), [Alt](https://github.com/goatslacker/alt) or [Fluxxor](https://github.com/BinaryMuse/fluxxor).

Alternatively, you can pass this initial state as a `prop` to the `Dashboard`, explicitly declaring that this is just the initial state.. like `initialData`, for instance. If you choose this path, though, you can't pass a different initial state to it aftwards, because it will "remember" the state after the first render.

**OBS**

You are not quite right in your definitions.

**State** is used to store mutable data, that is, data that is going to change during the component life-cycle. Changes in the state should be made through the `setState` method and will cause the component to re-render.

**Props** are used to pass in imutable data to the components. They should not change during the component life-cycle. Components that only use props are stateless.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928296/reactjs-how-to-pass-the-initial-state-while-rendering-a-component) is a relevant source on the "how to pass the initial state to components".

Comment: it is described very well, but... as always is a 'but'. What if I have component, which gets array of images and creates child components with thumbnails and onlick event, which should change big image in this component. Images are not in state, so I cannot use other component to maintain it. Images are local and I need some local state to manage which should be displayed as a big image. I would love to use props in state, but get Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.

Comment: so, any opinion on using `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` to set state?

Comment: componentWillRecieveProps() is deprecated as of 16.3 so ... No. Don't use it.

Comment: @Alejandro - [You probably don't need derived state](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html) is an in-depth explanation of the pitfalls in using (deprecated) `componentWillReceiveProps`, or its (not deprecated) replacement, `getDerivedStateFromProps`. Bottom line: article shows several alternative solutions, that *don't* call either of those methods, and explains why to use these alternatives instead.