# React.js - update radio or check input on re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have started writing a simple UI in React, and re-rendering input fields after an ajax call works fine on all components (text, select), except radio groups and checkboxes.

I can't for the life of me get checkboxes or radio groups to be correctly checked on a re-render after the "value" prop has been changed on a parent.
I *know* that the component is getting re-rendered from console output, and I also now that the checked/selected state is being calculated correctly. However this is never reflected in the UI, which remains in the state it was on the initial render.

Code is below:

```
//Mixin used for all form inputs        
var InputField = {
        isValid : function(){
            var input = this.state.value;
            var valid = true;
            if(this.props.validations !== undefined){
                for(var i = 0; i < this.props.validations.length;i++){
                    if(valid){
                        valid = this.props.validations[i](input);
                    }
                }
            }

            this.setState({isValid: valid});
            return valid;
        },

        componentWillReceiveProps: function(newProps){
            this.setState({value: newProps.value});
        },

        getInitialState: function() {
          return {value: this.props.value, isValid: true};
        }
    };
    //the actual component:
    var RadioButtons = React.createClass({
        mixins: [InputField],
        handleChange: function(){
            var props = this.props;
            var selectedOpts = _.map($(React.findDOMNode(this.refs.radiobuttons)).find(':checked'), function(opt){ return parseInt(opt.value); });
            var values = _.map(selectedOpts, function(index){
                return props.options[index];
            });
            if(values.length > 0)
                this.setState({value: values[0]});
            else
                this.setState({value: null});
        },

        render: function(){
            var showProp = this.props.show;
            var i = 0;
            var self = this;
            var options =  _.map(self.props.options,function(opt){
                var selected = show(self.state.value,showProp) === show(opt,showProp);
                console.log(selected);
                var result = (<label className="radio">
                        <span className="checked"><input type="radio" name={self.props.name} value={i} checked={selected} onChange={self.handleChange}>{show(opt,showProp)}</input></span>
                    </label>);
                i = i + 1;
                return result;
            });

            return ( <FormField label={this.props.label} fieldClass="col-md-8" ref="radiobuttons" errorMessage={this.props.errorMessage} isValid={this.state.isValid}> 
            {options}
                </FormField> 
                   );
        }

    });
```

I am somewhat baffled by this, and would appreciate any help..

**edit**
It seems every DOM element and value is set correctly, the only thing that is not happening is it being reflected visually.
Suspect this might be a general browser/JS issue rather than specifically React?

Answer (score 1):

> I can't for the life of me get checkboxes or radio groups to be
>   correctly checked on a re-render after the "value" prop has been
>   changed on a parent

That's because `getInitialState` is only called for the first render. And that's why you should avoid passing the initial state as a prop. [Here's an answer of mine regarding the same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28785106/reactjs-why-is-passing-the-component-initial-state-a-prop-an-anti-pattern/28785276#28785276).

If you want future renders to reflect the new props being passed in, do not store their values in the state.

React has the concept of `Controllable` and `Uncontrollable` components.

- `Controllable` components store very little state. They receive virtually everything as a `prop` and they expose `eventHandlers` to inform the parent when the "state" changes so the parent can render them again. As they don't store much state, they can't just `setState` to rerender. The parent has to do it.
- `Uncontrollable` components will work for themselves. They store state, and when you change them, they are able to rerender without the intervention of their parents. Future rerenders of `uncontrollable` components will not have much effect on their state.

Your `Radio` is acting as an `uncontrollable` component. And that's why it's not responding to `prop` changes.

Comment: This doesn't actually solve the problem: firstly, the mixin updates the state. Secondly, removing all mentions of state, and making the component props driven doesn't change anything: the visible UI of the component does not get updated as it gets new props - though the console output confirms that render _does_ get called.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this is not an issue with React, nor with the code above:
It seems *jquery.uniform.js*, which is on the page somehow interferes with showing check and radio box updates properly.

Nasty.