# ReactJS: How do I set the default value for input components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I get around the anti-pattern with state from props when using default values for input fields?

When the form is rendered, it should contain some default values. When I set some values and closes the form and then re-opens the form I want the default values to show, not the ones previously entered...

But when I let state inherit values from props, the props are changed forever. I haven't found a way to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the default `input` component, or the inputs from `react-bootstrap`, or most of the `DatePickers` and `Selects` on the internet, you will see that most of them have a `value` prop, and most of them will have little to none state, at least when it comes to the selected value.

An `input` is meant to be `uncontrolled`, meaning that they are better off not having state, and just receiving the value as a prop, as well as a callback they should call when the value changes. It's up to the `controller-view` above them, to watch these events and change the model. Some times it may be convenient for the inputs to keep the value in the state as well, but they can only do it as  long as they *respect* new value being passed as a prop, because the state persists in rerenders and `getInitialState` is only called once. See also: [ReactJS: Why is passing the component initial state a prop an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28785106/reactjs-why-is-passing-the-component-initial-state-a-prop-an-anti-pattern/28785276#28785276)

However, because it would be too cumbersome for the `controller-view` to handle all these value changes, React comes with an utility called [ReactLink](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html), which is, very briefly, a way to automatically bind an `input` to a property in the state of the `controller-view`. Example: You can bind an `input` to the property `DateOfBirth` of the model, which is part of the state of the `controller-view`.

Now back to your question, you don't actually pass the default value, you pass the value itself, as a prop. The `controller-view` should decide what it is. What is the value for the `DateOfBirth` field? None? Ok, I'll pass the default value as the `value` prop.

Comment: Thank you for an elaborate response.

I'm having problem wrapping my head around is this: handling the updated data from an input must be stored in state. Right?

So to get around the state-from-props problem I could initially set the value of the input to the value of the prop and then store the updated value in state. But then I have data spread across props and state which is a problem when I want to submit the data.

The anti-pattern way (that would make more sense if it'd worked), is to let state inhering the values from props. But that permanently alters the value of the props.