# React-Rails: .js.jsx file crashes Rails application

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, react-rails

I'm new to Rails and ReactJS.

I've been having a lot of issues rendering a simple "Hello World" component with the react-rails gem on Rails 5.0.2, running on Windows 7.

If I include a .js.jsx file in the components folder, my app crashes. Interestingly enough, if I replace it with the plain .js version of ReactJS (and change nothing else), my app doesn't crash and the component renders on my page. However, I would really like to learn to use JSX in my Rails app for the sake of learning, if anything else.

It says I have a SyntaxError, but this only confuses me, because using the regular JS version doesn't throw this error. So I'm guessing the JSX isn't getting transpiled to regular JavaScript or something? Does react-rails not have this built-in? Is this error related to a missing Gem in my Gemfile?

[This is the closest SO answer I found with the same problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40053702/react-rails-problems-getting-started) I tried downgrading to 4.2.5.1, but I still received the same problems.

I'd greatly appreciate any advice or pointers on the matter!

Error message in app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid character
...          
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

app/assets/javascripts/components/main.js.jsx

```
/** 
 * @jsx React.DOM 
 */

var Main = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
//I have also tried using React.renderComponent and gotten the same result
//I've also considered using class Main extends Component
```

app/views/index/helloworld.html.erb

```
<div id="content">
    ...
    <%= react_component('Main') %>
    //I have also tried <%= react_component 'Main' %> and gotten the same result
    ...
</div>
```

Gemfile:

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '5.0.2'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

# Fix issues with running Rails on Windows
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0' 

gem 'react-rails', '~> 1.7', '>= 1.7.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.1', '>= 4.1.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

To be sure, did you restart your development server (`rails s`) after installing the gem? It must be restarted to add the Sprockets processor for `.jsx`.

Could you add your complete `Gemfile.lock` also? I'm interested to see the Sprockets version and see what ExecJS backend you're using.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you trying to use ES6 syntax in your js.jsx component.

Here

```
var Main = React.createClass({
 -->>> render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

This should be:

```
var Main = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```