# Why does my React grandchild component not update after receiving a change in props from its parent? Or: do I need to use state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have tried finding the answer to this on StackOverflow and there are some related posts (e.g. [React Child Component Not Updating After Parent State Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41233458/react-child-component-not-updating-after-parent-state-change)) but I want to understand *why* this is not working...

I have a React application that will display a layout of character cards (that is, each card displays a different character).  It uses a child component, `CharacterBoard`, that lays out the `CharacterCards`, which would be a grandchild component.  I pass the `characters` down from the `App` to the `CharacterBoard` as props, and `CharacterBoard` in turn `map`s these out the `CharacterCard`s.

The problem is that I want the state of the `character` to change when I click on one of them.  Specifically, I want the `revealed` field to change.  However, even though the state change is reflected in the array of `character`s in the App (that is, the `revealed` field changes correctly), and the change is reflected in the array of `character`s in `CharacterBoard`,  but  not in `CharacterCard`.  In fact, my mapping does not seem to be called at all in `CharacterBoard` when the props change.

Do I need to use something like `getDerivedStateFromProps` in `CharacterBoard` and set the `state` of that component and then use the `state` to map the values down to `CharacterCard`?  If so, why?

In short (tl;dr), **can you pass props on down through the component chain and map them out along the way and still have all changes reflected automatically?**

Thanks for any guidance.

If it helps, the `render` method of my App is

```
render() {

    const {state: {characters}} = this
    return (
      <div>
        <header>
        </header>
        <main>
          <CharacterBoard
            onCardSelected={this.onCardSelected}
            rowSize={logic.ROW_SIZE}
            characters={characters}
            cardSize={this.CARD_SIZE}/>
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

that of `CharacterBoard` is

```
 render() {
    const {props: {characters, rowSize, cardSize,onCardSelected}} = this
    const rowUnit = 12 / rowSize

    const cardLayout = characters
      .map((character, i) => (
          <Col xs={6} sm={rowUnit} key={character.name}>
            <CharacterCard
              onCardSelected = {onCardSelected}
              key={i + Math.random()}
              character={character}
              cardSize={cardSize}
            />
          </Col>
        )
      )

    return (
      <div>
        <Container>
          <Row>
            {cardLayout}
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

and finally `CharacterCard` has this `render` method

```
 render() {
    const {props: {character, cardSize}} = this
    const {thumbnail, revealed} = character
    const imgURL = `${thumbnail.path}/${cardSize}.${thumbnail.extension}`

    const topCardClass = classNames('characterCard__card-back', {'characterCard__card-back--hidden': revealed})
console.log(revealed)
    return < a href="/#" onClick={this.onCardSelected}>
      <div className='characterCard__card'>
        <div className={topCardClass}>
          <img src="/images/card_back.png" alt=""/>
        </div>
        < div className='characterCard__card-front'>< img alt=''
                                                          src={imgURL}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>

  }
```

Comment: Passing props like that is quite normal and should work. Do you have any instances of `shouldComponentUpdate`? Those might cause it to not render. I do see one issue where you use a random key for the character card. You shouldn't do that, as it will force extra rerenders, but i don't think it's causing the problem you have.

Comment: @NicholasTower.  No, no `shouldComponentUpdate`.  I'll fix the random key issue and go back to the code do see if I can figure it out if it should be working as is.

Answer (score 0):

Doh!  A simple forgetting to `setState` in `App`. Knowing that it *should* work made me go back through the code one more time and see that, indeed, it was a stupid error on my part.