# React setState not re-rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In below code, state of Test is updating but its not re-rendering. I have updated the state of parent on button click on change of which I expected it to rerender the whole component including Button. But its not re-rendering Button. Need help wrt this. This is a test code and **both classes are necessary**.

```
import React from 'react';

class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props)
      this.state = {
          id : props.id
      }
  }
  render() {
      console.log('Button state id is', this.state.id)
      return(
          <div>
              'hi ' +  {this.state.id}
              <br/>
              <button type='submit' onClick={this.props.handleSubmit}>
                  submit
              </button>
          </div>
      )
  }
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
          id: 1
      }
      this.changeId = this.changeId.bind(this)
  }
  changeId() {
      let id = this.state.id
      console.log('parent state id is', id)
      this.setState({
          id: ++id
      })
  }
  render() {
      return(
          <Button id={this.state.id} handleSubmit={this.changeId}/>
      )
  }
}
```

EDIT: I have modified the code to remove obvious errors like not passing in `changeId` function to `Button`

EDIT 2: **Found the solution here: [React Child Component Not Updating After Parent State Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41233458/react-child-component-not-updating-after-parent-state-change)** `componentWillReceiveProps`

Comment: where is this id  id={id}

Comment: Did you forget passing handleSubmit={this.changeId} to your <Button> component in render if Test component? And I think it should be  {this.state.id} not just {id}

Comment: `id` is not defined in `changeId()`

Comment: May not be related to answering this question but worth mentioning here. @xploreraj, this is why I like using TypeScript along with React. It is much clearer as to what is there in our Props. You define props as an interface and declare the properties it is going to have. Same is the case with state.

Comment: yes, this is just code for this question, it should be `this.state.id`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Child Component Not Updating After Parent State Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41233458/react-child-component-not-updating-after-parent-state-change)

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` is `react` way!

Answer (score 3):

For a number to re render in the child component you need to make following changes to your code:

In current scenario value of id in changeId function is event, so you can't do ++id. You have to update it to:

```
changeId() {
    this.setState({
        id: ++this.state.id
    })
}
```

and for child component to re render the props value, you have to listen if there is any change in props. For that use componentDidUpdate lifecycle of react. Like this:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
   if (this.props.id !== prevProps.id) {
    this.setState({id: this.props.id});
  }
}
```

---

The other way is don't store props.id in child state. Use it directly in render.

```js
class Button extends React.Component {

  render() {
      return(
          <div>
              'hi ' +  {this.props.id}
              <br/>
              <button type='submit' onClick={this.props.handleSubmit}>
                  submit
              </button>
          </div>
      )
    }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
          id: 1
      }
      this.changeId = this.changeId.bind(this)
  }
  changeId() {
      this.setState({
          id: ++this.state.id
      })
  }
  render() {
      return(
          <Button id={this.state.id} handleSubmit={this.changeId}/>
      )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: You are right. But `componentWillReceiveProps` should be appropriate in my case.

Comment: @xplorerajL: componentWillRecieveProps is deprecated. It will still work but not advisable. [You can read here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops).

Answer (score 0):

You haven't actually passed `handleSubmit` as a prop to the `Button` component. Assuming you want `changeId()` to be called when you click the button, try this:

```
class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            id: 1
        }
        this.changeId = this.changeId.bind(this)
    }
    changeId() {
        console.log('change id called', id)
        this.setState({
            id: ++id
        })
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <Button id={id} handleSubmit={this.changeId}/>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: both classes necessary

Answer (score 0):

We can further optimise the component by doing something like this -: 
Highlights -:

- `changeId() {` changed to `changeId = () => {` (fat arrow notation), if we use this we don't need `this.changeId = this.changeId.bind(this)`;
- Don't really need another component specially for button, can combine it in same component.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'; 
export default class Test extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
            this.state = {
                id: 1
            }
        }
        changeId = () => {
            this.setState({
                id: ++this.state.id
            })
        }
        render() {
            return(
               <div>
                    'hi ' +  {this.state.id}
                    <br/>
                    <button type='submit' onClick={this.changeId}>
                        submit
                    </button>
                </div>
            )
        } }
```

Answer (score 0):

The example for `componentWillReceiveProps` worked in my case, when I wanted to update child component of React on `setState` of parent component:

```js
      componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
        this.setState({
          currentID: props.currentID
        });
      }
```