# Reactjs - update child component state when parent component state changes

Tags: reactjs

I am new to reactjs and I am not able to figure how to change child component state from parent component. Below is the code

```
<ChildComponent productCode={this.state.productCode} />
```

I would like the child component receive the `productCode` whenever a `setState` is done on `productCode` in the parent component.

Publishing an event from the parent component and subscribing to the event in the child component is on top of my head.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Child Component Not Updating After Parent State Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41233458/react-child-component-not-updating-after-parent-state-change)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does work, but note that the `Child` receives this data as a *prop*, not as a part of its internal `state`.

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 0,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section>
        Count: {this.state.count}
        <br />
        <button
          onClick={() =>
            this.setState((prevState) => ({
              count: prevState.count + 1,
            }))
          }
        >
          Increment Count
        </button>
        <Child passedCount={this.state.count} />
      </section>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <section>
        I am the child. The <code>count</code> * 2 ={' '}
        {/* Access `this.props.passedCount` to use the value */}
        <b>{this.props.passedCount * 2}</b>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, rootElement);
```

```css
section {
    background: beige;
    padding: 1em;
}

section > section {
    background: sandybrown;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `childState` is your child state, if you are working with class component you have to add to your class a `componentWillReceiveProps` hook life cycle.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  this.setState({ childState: nextProps.productCode});  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have run exactly into the reason why people use state containers. I can only suggest trying out redux, mobx or mobx-state-tree.

If you really don't want to dive into these tools, things get a little tricky, you can do it anyway if you insist, but I would advise against.

Proceed like this: first write a function in the parent that alters it state, then hand that function over to the child component, after that call that function in the child. Here is a code example, you might fiddle with it a little though:

```
// the parent
function parent() {
   const [state, setState] = useState('')

   const update = () => {
      setState("new state")
   }

   return(<Child updateFunction={update} />)
}

// the cild
function Child(props) {
   return(
      <FancyComponent
         onClick={props.update}
      />
   )
}
```