# Updating child component when a value in parent changes in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I'm calling this child component like this

```
<FilterItem filterOption={filterOption} updateFilter={updateFilter} value={filter[filterOption.fieldName]}/>
```

and setting the value in the input tags with those values

```
<div style={{padding: 5}}>
            <input 
                type={props.filterOption.type} 
                {...props.filterOption.additionalAttr} 
                onChange={(event) => changeFilter(event)} 
                field={props.filterOption.fieldName}
                value={props.filterOption.value}
                checked={props.filterOption.value}
            /> 
            <span>{props.filterOption.label}</span>
</div>
```

but once the value is set, it is not changing even if I change the values in parent component.

Is there a way to achieve this?
I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41233458/react-child-component-not-updating-after-parent-state-change), but as someone who as some experience with ember, I feel like there has to be a simple solution

edit:-

The state in parent is defined like this

```
const [filter, setFilter] = useState({});
```

and the state is changed in this method

```
const updateFilter = (key, value) => {
    var tempFilter = filter;
    tempFilter[key] = value;
    setFilter(tempFilter);
};
```

this method is called from the child

```
const changeFilter = (event) => {

    var key = event.target.getAttribute("field");
    var value = (() => {
        switch(event.target.type){
            case "checkbox":
                return event.target.checked;
            case "range":
                return event.target.value
        }
    })();
    
    props.updateFilter(key, value)
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you are changing the values in parent. You need to make sure that you aren't mutating the state. If you mutate the state react cannot identify change .

Comment: How are you changing the values of the parent component? If you are wanting to update the state, the parent component should pass down the state information:
`<FilterItem filterOption={this.state.filterOption} updateFilter={this.state.updateFilter} value={filter[this.state.filterOption.fieldName]}/>`

Comment: @RobinClower I'm using functional components, I believe sending statename will be same as this.state.statename