# React functional component not updating on setState from parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, apollo

My React component uses apollo to fetch data via graphql

```
class PopUpForm extends React.Component {

  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {
      shoptitle: "UpdateMe",
      popupbodyDesc: "UpdateMe"
    }
  }

render() 
{
    return (
        <>
        <Query query={STORE_META}>
          {({ data, loading, error, refetch }) => {
            
       
            if (loading) return <div>Loading…</div>;
            if (error) return <div>{error.message}</div>;
            if (!data) return (
              <p>Could not find metafields :(</p>
            );

            console.log(data);
             //loop over data
              var loopedmetafields = data.shop.metafields.edges
              console.log(loopedmetafields)
              loopedmetafields.forEach(element => {
                console.log(element.node.value)
                if (element.node.value === "ExtraShopDescription"){
                  
                  this.setState({
                    shoptitle: element.node.value
                  });
                  console.log(this.state.shoptitle)
                }
                if (element.node.value === "bodyDesc"){
                   
                  this.setState({
                    popupbodyDesc: element.node.value
                  });
                  console.log(this.state.popupbodyDesc)
                }
              });
            return (
              <>
                <AddTodo  mkey="ExtraShopDesc" namespace="ExtraShopDescription" desc={this.state.shoptitle} onUpdate={refetch} />
                <AddTodo  mkey="body" namespace="bodyDesc" desc={this.state.popupbodyDesc} onUpdate={refetch} />
              </>
            );
        }}
        </Query>
        </>
    )
    }
}

export default PopUpForm
```

Frustratingly the functional component renders before the state is set from the query. Ideally the functional component would only render after this as I thought was baked into the apollo library but seems I was mistaken and it seems to execute synchronous rather than asynchronous

As you can see I pass the props to the child component, in the child component I use these to show the current value that someone might amend

The functional component is here

```
 function AddTodo(props) {

let input;
const [desc, setDesc] = useState(props.desc);
//console.log(desc)

useEffect( () => {
  console.log('props updated');
  console.log(props)
}, [props.desc])

const [addTodo, { data, loading, error }] = useMutation(UPDATE_TEXT, {
    refetchQueries: [
        'STORE_META' // Query name
      ],
});

//console.log(data)
if (loading) return 'Submitting...';
if (error) return `Submission error! ${error.message}`;

return (
  <div>
    <form
      onSubmit={e => {
        console.log(input.value)
        setDesc(input.value)
        e.preventDefault();
        const newmetafields = {
            key: props.mkey,
            namespace: props.namespace,
            ownerId: "gid://shopify/Shop/55595073672",
            type: "single_line_text_field",
            value: input.value
        }
        addTodo({ variables: { metafields: newmetafields } });
        input.value = input.value
      }}
    >
        <p>This field denotes the title of your pop-up</p>
      <input className="titleInput" defaultValue={desc} 
        ref={node => {
          input = node;
        }}
      />
      <button className="buttonClick" type="submit">Update</button>
    </form>

  </div>
);
```

}

Now I need this component to update when the setState is called on PopUpForm

Another stack overflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41233458/react-child-component-not-updating-after-parent-state-change) gives me some clues

> Passing the intial state to a component as a prop is an anti-pattern
> because the getInitialState (in our case the constuctor) method is
> only called the first time the component renders. Never more. Meaning
> that, if you re-render that component passing a different value as a
> prop, the component will not react accordingly, because the component
> will keep the state from the first time it was rendered. It's very
> error prone.

Hence why I then implemented useEffect however the console.log in useEffect is still "updateMe" and not the value as returned from the graphql call.

So where I'm at

- I need the render the functional component after the the grapql call
  and I've manipulated the data, this seems to be the best approach in terms of design patterns also

or

- I need setState to pass/render the functional component with the new value

As an aside if I do this

```
            <AddTodo  mkey="ExtraShopDesc" namespace="ExtraShopDescription" desc={data.shop.metafields.edges[0].node.value} onUpdate={refetch} />
```

It will work but I can't always expect the value to be 0 or 1 as metafields might have already defined

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a simpler way than using `setState` to solve this. You can for example use `find` like this:

```js
              const shopTitleElement = loopedmetafields.find(element => {
                return element.node.value === "ExtraShopDescription"
              })
              const shopBodyElement = loopedmetafields.find(element => {
                return element.node.value === "bodyDesc"
              });
              return (
              <>
                <AddTodo  mkey="ExtraShopDesc" namespace="ExtraShopDescription" desc={shopTitleElement.node.value} onUpdate={refetch} />
                <AddTodo  mkey="body" namespace="bodyDesc" desc={shopBodyElement.node.value} onUpdate={refetch} />
              </>
            );
```